# C++ How to retrieve ACK from a TCP Socket (windows)

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, tcp

I have some issues getting information about the acknowledgement of a TCP connection.

I've implemented a basic TCP Socket Server (socket(), listen(), bind(), accept(), send()) using Windows sockets. The communication works fine but now I want to retrieve and observe the incoming acknowledgements of the TCP packet.

Does anyone knows how I can get this information programmatically?

Comment: You may use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to observe the incoming/outgoing packet.

Comment: These are being handled for you by the networking layer you're using. As @ymonad said, you can capture and view them with wireshark. I don't believe windows sockets allows you to access them though.

Comment: You can't, unless you use raw sockets. Why do you think you need this? In general, acknowledgements in TCP are only detected via the absence of subsequent failures.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I already figured out how to sniff the connection via raw sockets. I also considered Wireshark but unfortunately I need to analyse a communication via WLAN and Bluetooth under Windows and there is no support for Bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

If your ***application*** needs to know **when** the data is received, or even in the case of failure, **how much** was received, you need an ***application-level*** acknowledgement.

The TCP ACK does not belong to the Application layer, it is purely layer-4 book-keeping information. If layer7 needs an ACK you need to add one at layer 7.

Related, the same goes for keep-alives: [Asyncsockets and "silent" disconnections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338352/asyncsockets-and-silent-disconnections/5338459#5338459)

Comment: Thank you Ben! For my analysis I send added an ACK on layer 7, cause I can't find a solution that works for both Bluetooth and WLAN socket under windows.